# RegEx match string between string and first empty line

Tags: regex

I have some text:

```
Value1
sub values1
sub values1

Value2
sub value2
sub value2

Value3
...and so on
```

I want to use RegEx to retrieve everything between Value1 and the first empty line
There is an added complication that `Value1` may, at times be appended with `.addition` so I need to include that also.
so I may be looking at

```
Value1
sub values1
sub values1

Value1.addition
sub value2
sub value2
```

Where I want to match one or the other, in my example just `Value1`

The output im looking for is

```
sub values1
sub values1
```

Comment: Please can you provide the regex where you got stuck for being able to find problem with your pattern and what regex flavor/tool/language you're using.

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/iZ6uY9/4)? Get group 2 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work in .NET:

```
"(?<=(\A|\n)Value1.*\n).*(\n.*)*?(?=\n\s*\n|\Z)"
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not be possible to select `Value 1` over `Value 1.addition` by just using regular expressions, but you can do that quite easily using a simple if-statement in whatever language you are using. The following regular expression should work for you.

```
/^(Value(\d+))(.*)$((?:\r?\n^.+$)*)\r?\n^$/gm
```

If applied to your first example string the results will be:

```
group #1: Value1
group #2: 1
group #3: 
group #4: sub values1
          sub values1

group #1: Value2
group #2: 2
group #3: 
group #4: sub value2
          sub value2
```

Applying this to your second example string has the following result:

```
group #1: Value1
group #2: 1
group #3: 
group #4: sub values1
          sub values1

group #1: Value1
group #2: 1
group #3: .addition
group #4: sub value2
          sub value2
```

Now you can simply compare group 2, check wether group 3 has a value or not and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```python
import re

txt = '''
Value1
sub values1
sub values1

Value1.addition
sub value12
sub value12

Value2
sub value2
sub value2'''

match1 = re.search('Value1\n([\s\S]*?)\n\n', txt)
match1_addition = re.search('Value1\.addition\n([\s\S]*?)\n\n', txt)
values1 = match1.groups()[0] + '\n' + match1_addition.groups()[0]
print(values1)
```

returns

```
sub values1
sub values1
sub value12
sub value12
```

Regex explanation:

- `Value1\n`: Look for text that starts with `Value1` followed by a new line
- `(...)`: matching group, which is the content that we want

  - `[...]*?`: lazy matching, that is, as few characters as possible
  - `[\s\S]`: any whitespace characters (space, tab, newline) – `\s` – or non-whitespace character – `\S`
- `\n\n`: two newline characters, representing an empty line